# Routing with slim and codeigniter in one application?

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, slim

I got a problem with routing in my application. My folder structure looks like:

- application
- css
- images
- js
- svc // Slim Application Folder
- index.php
- .htaccess

If I call a slim route http://www.mydomain.de/svc/hello/world I get an 404 Error from codeigniter. My htaccess in the root looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L]
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to add an other `RewriteRule` before the current one to handle `^svc` requests and if that won't match fall back to the codeigniter's front controller (the slim rewrite lifted from [its source](https://github.com/codeguy/Slim/blob/master/.htaccess))

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^svc svc/index.php [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]
```

Comment: Maybe my test setup was not mirroring yours correctly, I've removed leading slashes, please try again.

Comment: Doesn't work. Did I have to change the Slim .htaccess in the svc folder, too?

Comment: I think you don't need that .htaccess there, if you make the one in the parent directory work.

Comment: Have you tried to remove the svc/.htaccess file? (maybe we should try to resolve this in chat, SO doesn't encourage long comment threads)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14341/discussion-between-grolle-and-complex857)